# Getting the value of a checkbox inside another component when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, the parent App component and a child component (Checkbox component) in this scenario. I have a checkbox inside the child component when this checkbox is clicked or checked.

I want the result to be displayed on the console only when a button is clicked inside the parent component. What I have presently is only showing on the console when the checkbox is checked and this is happening inside the child component.

```
import { useState } from "react";

// import Checboxtest from "./Checkboxtest";
import "./styles.css";

// const Person = props => (
const Checboxtest = ()=> {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  const [checkboxvalue, setcheckboxvalue] = useState("");
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
    setcheckboxvalue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Checkbox Value </h1>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="Orange"
        name="Orange"
        value="Orange"
        checked={isChecked}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      />
      Orange
      {isChecked ? console.log(checkboxvalue) : console.log("nill")}
    </div>
  );
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>When clicked on the button below, the value of the checkbox inside the child component should be display on the console.</h1>
      <button>See checkbox value</button>
      <Checboxtest  />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `state` value to control this scenario. It can be implemented in your `App` component or inside of your `Checkbox` component.

Let implement the state in the parent component, so define a state in the `App` component:

```
export default function App() {
  // create a state value
  const [showResult, setShowResult] = useState(false);
  // create handler 
  const handleShowResult = () => setShowResult(prevState => !prevState)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>When clicked on the button below, the value of the checkbox inside the child component should be display on the console.</h1>
      <button onClick={handleShowResult}>See checkbox value</button>
      <Checboxtest  showResult={showResult}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When you click on the button, the `showResult` value will change. the `showResult` props will pass the state of checkbox result visibility to the `Checkbbox` component.

Now, implement the `showResult` props in the `Checkbox`:

```
const Checboxtest = ({showResult})=> {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  const [checkboxvalue, setcheckboxvalue] = useState("");

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
    setcheckboxvalue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Checkbox Value </h1>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="Orange"
        name="Orange"
        value="Orange"
        checked={isChecked}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      />
      // check showResult value 
      Orange
      {showResult ? console.log(checkboxvalue) : console.log("nill")}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage state on the parent component i.e. in `App.js` and pass the `isChecked` and `changeCheckBoxValue` to `Checboxtest`. so that checked value is propagated to parent value and when you click button, `App.js` component has all details.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// import Test from './Test';
import Checboxtest from './Checboxtest';

const App = () => {
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState( false );
    const [checkboxvalue, setcheckboxvalue] = useState("nil");

    const changeCheckBoxValue = (e) => {
        const val = e.target.value;
        setIsChecked(state => !state);
        isChecked ? setcheckboxvalue("nil"): setcheckboxvalue(val);
    }

    const seeCheckedValue = () => {
        console.log( checkboxvalue )
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="App">
                <h1>When clicked on the button below, the value of the checkbox inside the child component should be display on the console.</h1>
                <button onClick={seeCheckedValue}>See checkbox value</button>
                <Checboxtest isChecked={isChecked}
                             changeCheckBoxValue={changeCheckBoxValue}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

**Checboxtest Component**

```
const Checboxtest = ( { isChecked, changeCheckBoxValue } ) => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Checkbox Value </h1>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                id="Orange"
                name="Orange"
                value="Orange"
                checked={isChecked}
                onChange={changeCheckBoxValue}
            />
            Orange
        </div>
    );
}

export default Checboxtest
```